# Little complicated representation of fraction with ProfCollege

Tags: teaching

Is it possible to produce representation of this fraction with `ProfCollege`package ?

My MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ProfCollege}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

Simple representation of fraction :

 \Fraction[Rectangle,Reponse]{1/4}

And this is a little complicated:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)rectangle(4,4);
\fill[red](0,4)rectangle(1,3);
\draw (2,0)--(2,4);
\draw (0,2)--(4,2);
\draw[gray](1,4)--(1,2);
\draw[gray] (0,3)--(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think so. You might want to ask the author of the package (see the package documentation  for the email address), maybe he is willing to extend his package.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I guess. I'll send a message.